# How to delete all data of a json document except the key/value I want

Tags: json, regex, notepad++

So I have a rather big document with entries like:

```
"kff126d":"Infinity"
```

And others like:

```
"kff126d":"0.03702955"
```

And a few dozens of other keys like kff126e and so on, and I would like to remove everything that isn't the one key I want to keep, and whatever value is inside the second set of quotation marks, so I can take a look at abnormal values.

Could someone help me out? I've tried looking arround but it's quite complex compared to the few things I've done with regex before this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No idea what you need. Just keep the `"kff126d":"[^"]*"` pattern and remove all that does not match it?

Comment: yes exactly, keep anything that is after the : and between "", and ignore everything else that does not match that first key left of :

Comment: I can suggest `("kff126d":"[^"]*")|(?:(?!"kff126d":).)+` (with *`.` matches newline* option ON) and replace with `$1\n` (after that, you can remove empty lines with `Edit` > `Line Operations` > `Remove Empty Lines`

Comment: That worked!!! Thank you very much. Unfortunately I do not have level enough to tell why the other answers didn't and yours did, but thanks a bunch!!! Only works if I do it one by one thought, not sure what is going on. Has notepad a character limit or something for replacing all??

Comment: I will add an answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can suggest the following regex:

```
("kff126d":"[^"]*")|(?:(?!"kff126d":).)+
```

with *`.` matches newline* option ON, and replace with `$1\n`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dL5aI9/3)

This will insert redundant empty lines that you can remove with **Edit** > **Line Operations** > **Remove Empty Lines**.

The point is to match  *and capture* with `(...)` the part that you need to keep, and remove all the rest. *All the rest* can be matched with a *tempered greedy token* `(?:(?!"kff126d":).)+` (matches any character (with `.`) that does not start the `"kff126d":` sequence).

[image]

                                                                                  V
[image]

And here is the screen of the replacement result with your updated sample data:

[image]

Comment: I edited a bit too late, but, if I do this line by line, it works, if I use replace all, it does nothing. That has obviously nothing to do with the regex (imho) but would you happen to know why this happens??

Comment: You must have forgotten to enable DOTALL mode with the *`.` matches newline*. Please see the settings in my screenshot.

Comment: Nop, I did enable it and am using it. Is it possible to fail for very big documents/with a lot of convoluted info? Logic says no but.. it really does delete everything, and I do not believe 3 users answering this are in the wrong, it's kind of weird

Comment: Please paste a bit of your data into the question body. Also, if your document is huge, you'd better use a more optimized regex, like [`("kff126d":"[^"]*")|(?=.)[^"]*(?:"(?!kff126d":)[^"]*)*`](https://regex101.com/r/tI8yX3/1) with the same replacement (`$1\n`)

Comment: Allright I just saw your tool that you used as an example and it's working damn nice, so I'm just going to use that and see how many characters I can input there until it breaks, so thank you very much for your help

Comment: I will add data in the question body now, 1 minute, sorry for the trouble

Comment: If you still have issues, try updating NPP, I have v6.9.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> and in the find section use : `(?m)^(?!"kff126d":).*?$` and leave the replace section blank. Select the search mode 'Regular Expression' and select <kbd>Replace All</kbd>.

This will transform

```
"kff126d":"0.12345"
sdfgsdfg
sgsfgsfg
"kff126d":"0.03702955"
"kff126d":"0.03702955"
rererer
"kff126d":"0.03702955"
sfdgsfgfsg
sdfgsfg
"kff126e":"0.8888888888888"
```

into

```
"kff126d":"0.12345"


"kff126d":"0.03702955"
"kff126d":"0.03702955"

"kff126d":"0.03702955"
```

Afterwards, if you want to remove all the blank lines, you can replace `\R+` with `\n`

Answer (score 1):

## Description

Using Notepad++:

- find all characters that is not the desired key name
- which are also not the value `Infinity`
- work with json strings which are not neatly padded, aka compressed json
- leave behind a vertical column of values

**The Regex**

Find What:

```
.*?(?:"kff126e":"((?!Infinity)[^"]*)"|\Z)
```

Replace with:

```
$1\n
```

## How To

From Notepad++

1. press the <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> to enter the find and replace
   mode
2. Select the Regular Expression option
3. Select the ". matches newline" option
4. In the "Find what" field place the following regex
   `.*?(?:"kff126e":"((?!Infinity)[^"]*)"|\Z)`
5. In the Replace with field enter `$1\n` Click <kbd>Replace All</kbd>
6. Goto pub for favorite beverage.

## Explanation

[image: Regular expression visualization]

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character (0 or more times (matching
                           the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "kff126e":"              '"kff126e":"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        Infinity                 'Infinity'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \Z                       before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
```

**What's happening**

The desired value will be placed into capture group 1 aka `$1`, which will replace the matched text. The `\n` inserts a return character.  The regex engine will continue parsing your text after the last replace operation until it reaches the end of the file.

Comment: That deletes everything in the document, same as answer above. I am not sure why, I did think it would work. If it helps, I have veeeery long lines like "kff1204":"0.21636446","kff1223":"-0.07113578","kff1249":"8.4292755","kff1263":"10.550725" and when I replace it one by one, it just deletes one line at a time?? It seems weird tbh.